# Problem with using NSolve to find a zero of a function that is restricted to taking a numeric argument

Tags: equation-solving, evaluation

I want to use NSolve to find the root of a function `myFun` that is only meaningful when evaluated on a numeric argument:

```
Clear[myFun];
myFun[x_?NumericQ] := N[Sin[x]]

myFun[1]
(* 0.841471 *)

NSolve[{myFun[x] == 0.5, x > 0, x < 2}, x]    
(* NSolve[{myFun[x] == 0.5, x > 0, x < 2}, x] *)

NSolve[{N[Sin[x]] == 0.5, x > 0, x < 2}, x]
(* {{x -> 0.523599}} *)
```

As can be seen from the code, NSolve wold not find the numeric root of `myFun[x]==0.5`, but works well when the right hand side of `myFun`'s definition is manually supplied to the code.

In reality `myfun` would be some complicated function (such as functions involving numerical routines like `Findfit`), that only returns meaningful answer when its argument is numeric. I wonder if there is a way in Mathematica to find its numerical root, as can be easily achieved in C or Python.

Also I do not have much idea why this happens in the first place. I tried to do a `Trace` on the third expression in the code above and it seems that Mathematica first evaluated `myFun[x]`. But since `x` is not numeric the evaluation does not rewrite anything, and the very same expression is returned back again. But this just makes me feel confused about how it happens that an expression like

```
NSolve[{Sin[x] == 0.5, x > 0, x < 2}, x]
```

does produce a numerical solution. Why doesn't `Sin[x]` evaluate to `Sin[x]` and make it impossible to progress?

I would be grateful if someone can share his/her idea on this!

Comment: Use `FindRoot`. `NSolve` is the `N` variant of `Solve`, which tries to find ALL solutions to equations, and is primarily meant for polynomial equations (but can handle some non-trancendental trig. and exp. equations as well)

Comment: @Marius Ladegård Meyer: Yeah `FindRoot` does work! Would you mind reposting your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m_goldberg has explained why `NSolve` doesn't work here, if your function does need `?Numeric` you probably want to use `FindRoot` to solve it:

```
FindRoot[myFun[x] - 0.5, {x, 0, 2}]
(* {x -> 0.523599} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

When `f` is defined by

```
Clear[f]
f[x_?NumericQ] := N[Sin[x]]
```

the pattern `x_?NumericQ` prevents `NSolve` from evaluating `f[x]` to `N[Sin[x]]`, so as far as `NSolve` is concerned, `f` may as well not be defined at all. It has no idea what kind of equation it has been given and refuses to solve it. However,

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := N[Sin[x]]
NSolve[{f[x] == 0.5, 0 < x < 2}, x]
```

works fine and gives

> `{{x -> 0.523599}}`